# Defining a Finite Displacement Vector Using Polar Unit Vectors

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, displacement

I believe I understand how to define positions using polar unit vectors.  However, I'm stuck on how to define finite displacements using said vectors.  I keep bumping up against the fact that such a displacement spans two positions, each defined by a different radial unit vector.  Is my only recourse to use Cartesian unit vectors to represent such a displacement?

Comment: in a nutshell: yes.  Adding or subtracting vector is only practical in Cartesian unless you have a really special geometry.

Comment: Do you mean trying to find the vector that points from polar coordinate $(r=1,\theta=π)$ to polar coordinate $(r=3,\theta=\pi/4)$, for example?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: I'm interested in what you mean by "special geometry."  Could I ask you to briefly describe one?

Comment: @BioPhysicist:  Indeed.  The displacement between those two positions is finite.  How might I define it using using polar unit vectors?

Comment: yes the vectors might be colinear for instance.  It is possible to add vectors in the plane: the method of phasors basically does this (see  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#:~:text=In%20physics%20and%20engineering%2C%20a,%CE%B8)%20are%20time%2Dinvariant.&text=The%20only%20difference%20in%20their,the%20complex%20amplitude%20(phasor). )However, it’s a mess in practice, and while there’s a closed form expression for the length, getting the angle can only be done implicitly.     Adding $3$ vectors that way is nigh impossible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you specify *where* the displacement vector is located.

In Cartesian coordinates, the unit vectors are constant over space, and hence they are expressed in the same way no matter the location. This is not true for polar coordinates though. For example, the vector $\mathbf v=v\,\hat x$ in Cartesian coordinates will be $v\,\hat r$ if its tail is located at $(x=1,y=0)$, but it will be $v\,\hat\theta$ if its tail is located at $(x=0,y=-1)$. This is why conversions between Cartesian and polar vectors involve not only the vector components but also spatial coordinates.

Now, I suppose you could get away with this by saying you will put the vector tails at the starting coordinate. So you could say, for example, the displacement vector from $(x=1,y=0)$ to $(x=1,y=4)$ is equal to $4\,\hat\theta$, but it's not a unique representation, as shown above.